# HttpHeaders and lazyupdate Angular 4 and Karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular4-httpclient

I have a problem with HttpHeaders (angular 4.3.0) and Karma. I write some tests and when I run them with npm test command, the http queries are unauthorized because the token (X-Auth-Token) is not set. when I run the same part in my browser with the console, the X-Auth-Token is set and everything works well.

The only difference I can see is in the HttpHeaders object and precisely in lazyUpdate.

**no test mode**

[image]

**With karma**

[image]

The code :

category.service.spec.ts

```
    describe('Service : Category', () => {

  // setup
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientModule, LocalStorageModule.withConfig(localStorageConfig), TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader }
      })],
      providers: [CategoryService, LoaderService, LocalStorageService
      ]
    }));


    it('should list the categories', () => {

        let categoryService = TestBed.get(CategoryService);

        categoryService.apiRoutes = ApiCategoryRoutes;
        categoryService.modelName = "category";

        let actualCategories = [];

        // categoryService expends APIResolverService
        let observable = categoryService.find(); 

        observable.subscribe(data => {

            actualCategories = data;
        });

        console.log("actualCategories");
        console.log(actualCategories);

    });

 });
```

apiResolver.service.ts (categoryService extends it, category service has no specific code)

```
export abstract class APIResolverService {

...

  public find() {

      this.showLoader();

      let url = this.getUrl(0, true);

      let headers = this.setHttpHeaders(); 

      console.log("headers");
      console.log(headers);

      let observable = this.http.get(url, {headers : headers})
      .map(res => this.manageResponse(res, true, true)).share();

      observable.subscribe(data => this.hideLoader(), error => this.hideLoader());

      return observable;
  }

  ...

    public setHttpHeaders(){

      let valueToken: string = JSON.stringify(this.localStorage.get('token'));

      let myHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .set('Accept-Language', "en")
      .set('X-Auth-Token', valueToken.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));

      return myHeaders;
  }

}
```

Somebody could explain this ?

Comment: can you post the http code?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Anyone ? I'm still stuck :(

Comment: It's odd the Accept-Language header is undefined (in lazyUpdate) & doesn't show up in headers. I wonder if this has anything to do with localStorage & Karma. What happens if you remove the x-auth-token?

Comment: Hi @Joe Allen, I know this has been a while ago. Did you find the solution? I am having similar difficulty with other headers. Cheers

Comment: I just had the same problem. For me it was the ´Accept-Language´ header being undefined during tests. My translation service in the interceptor was not mocked correctly. When this header has a value the request headers are all there in tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while testing an interceptor which was setting some request headers. What I was doing wrong during the test was not setting one of the headers (leaving it `undefined`) - I haven't looked that deep into the Angular code but this seems to leave out the 'lazyInit' property set to `null` which in place will stop triggering the 'init' call (that basically sets the headers):

```
    HttpHeaders.prototype.init = function () {
        var _this = this;
        if (!!this.lazyInit) {
            if (this.lazyInit instanceof HttpHeaders) {
                this.copyFrom(this.lazyInit);
            }
            else {
                this.lazyInit();
            }
            this.lazyInit = null;
            if (!!this.lazyUpdate) {
                this.lazyUpdate.forEach(function (update) { return _this.applyUpdate(update); });
                this.lazyUpdate = null;
            }
        }
    };
```

There's an issue on github which refers to this. See [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18743#issuecomment-323215006) comment.